# Is this a good place to ask law questions?

Tags: support, scope, legal

So, I was wondering(since this is pretty strict community), if I want to ask for law questions, can I ask for them here or is there some kind of law.stackoverflow.com? I've googled and all I found was some area51 which have deleted its law section or something like that...

Comment: If you need to ask a lawyer, you need to ask a lawyer.

Answer (score 5):

Certainly random legal questions, even if they were allowed *somewhere*, have nothing to do with programming and aren't on-topic here.

There have been various site proposals for such questions, and none have made it to beta (to my knowledge). Most run into the issue of liability in giving out legal advice.

If you have a legal question about *software*, its still not on topic here, but [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) accepts licensing questions. Please check their meta and help center first to make sure your question would be acceptable. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Without a specific example, its very unlikely any legal question (even about software/programming) would be on-topic here.

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, just a programmer, and as such none of the above should be construed as legal advice. It also doesn't mean any given question will be accepted on any given site. Please contact *an actual lawyer* regarding legal matters.

^^ (*see why we don't have Law.SE?*)

Comment: Disclaimer: My upvote is no legal advice either...